# UrlRewriteRule using Tuckey

Tags: java, web, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

How can I lowercase every letter in the url using tuckey UrlRewrite? this is what I have now, but doesn't seem to be working.

`<rule match-type="regex">
        <from>(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">${lower:$1}</to>
</rule>`

Answer (score 2):

You should put a condition for checking upper case letters.
Try this

```
<rule>
   <name>Force  URL's that contain upper case letter to lower case</name>
   <condition type="request-uri" casesensitive="true">^.*[A-Z].*$</condition>
   <from>^(.*)$</from>
   <to type="permanent-redirect">${lower:$1}</to>
</rule>
```